# Defining Dihedral groups using reflections.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, dihedral-groups

I'm trying to understand Dihedral groups $D_n$ of order $2n$. I'm a beginner at Group theory and my textbook uses Dihedral groups to motivate Group Theory so I haven't really began studyng group theory yet and hence I do not understand the "relators" or "free groups" or "presentation" yet so if you could use simple English to answer my question, I'd appreciate it.

I often (frankly always) see dihedral groups being defined using rotational and reflection symmetries like so:

$r$ is rotation of $n-$gon by $2π/n$ and $f$ is reflection about a fixed axis.

So, $D_n = \{r^if^j \left(\text{ or } f^j r^i \right) : 1≤i≤n, 1≤j≤2\}$

My question is, is it possible to define $D_n$ without using rotational symmetries, at all?

If you multiply two reflections you end up with a rotation. So is it possible to define $D_n$ by using $f_1,f_2, \ldots, f_n$ being reflections about each of the $n$ axes then $$D_n= \{f_i^a f_j^b: 1≤a,b≤2, 1≤i,j≤n \}$$

Two interesting questions arise here:

1. Why use rotational symmetries at all? Multiplying reflections produces rotations but two rotations do not produce a reflection. Isn't the second definition better or are there shortcomings to it?
2. Does this change the number of generators? In the first definition, $D_n$ is generated by two guys: $r$ and $f$ while in the second definition, you have $n$ generators?

Comment: You can define it via the presentation $$\langle a, b\mid a^n, b^2, bab^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle.$$

Comment: @Shaun Sorry, I don't get it. What part of my question are you answering to? I know that presentation, that is just rewriting of my first definition, no? But what are you trying to say with it?

Comment: Nowhere in your question, @William, do you mention presentations.

Comment: @William Perhaps this might help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group .

Comment: @Shaun Sorry my question is much more elementary than that. I haven't studied group theory into depth yet. I'm simply asking if my definition of dihedral groups make sense and if so, why is not more commonly used or if there are shortcomings to it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @MichaelCohen I don't know, that link talks about relators, free groups and what not. Maybe I should've mentioned it at the start, I'm very new to Group theory. In fact, my group theory textbook explains dihedral groups to motivate group theory so I haven't even really started with it. This question is supposed to be beginner level question. Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my question.

Comment: Your definition has one fundamental problem, namely that it only lists the elements of $D_n$ without imposing any restrictions on how they multiply. That is also the fundamental difference between what you have written and the presentation given by Shaun. Shaun's presentation uniquely determines $D_n$ by giving the orders of the generators and a relation telling you how to multiply them together.

Comment: @Möb This might be a dumb question what do you mean when you say, my definition does not say how they (reflections) multiply? I guess multiplication is just composition here, no? I've already given some context in the text so I figured I shouldn't add that into the set description for brevity i.e. $f_i$ is reflection so $f_i f_j$ is just reflection $f_j$ followed by reflection $f_i$, what am I missing?

Comment: Sure you can try to avoid talking about rotations explicitly. The point is if you pick two reflections carefully, their composition will give you a rotation that generates the rotation subgroup. So you can replace whatever relations involving $r,f$ into relations involving reflections alone. However, it is often convenient to be able to talk about rotations directly, e.g. to describe the center of $D_{2n}$ or write down a solvable series for it.

Comment: @IEm makes sense. So you're saying that the two sets are indeed same $D_n$, right? No matter how I choose to write them! I'm trying to understand why the first one is "nicer" than the second one. Could it be because it involves less symbols (only $r$ and $f$) so it's convenient while the second definition involves $n$ different symbols? Is that all? Or is there something more to it?

Comment: In fact, there is an area of group theory dedicated to studying groups that are generated by elements of order $2$ with a certain type of presentation: it is the theory of [Coxeter groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group), and dihedral groups are examples of Coxeter groups. However, dihedral groups are also often used as early examples of easy groups that are not abelian, and in that respect it is much easier to think of them in terms of rotations and reflections ("rigid motions of the regular $n$-gon") than to think of them only in terms of reflections and their compositions.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that a group is not just a set, it is a set endowed with a particular algebraic structure. To put it simply: To define a group it does not suffice to list the elements of the underlying set, you also have to define an operation on that set satisfying the group axioms. The statements

$$D_n = \{f^i r^j | 1 \leq i \leq 2, 1 \leq j \leq n \} $$

does not make sense on its own because it does not tell you how all these elements multiply. When you say that multiplication is just composition, you assume that you know what composition means and that forces you to go back to thinking about reflections and flips of an $n$-gon. You can avoid this by giving what is known as a group presentation. In a group presentation, you give a number of generators, their orders and a number of relations that uniquely determine the multiplication of all elements. In the case of $D_n$ such a presentation is

$$ \langle r, f | r^n = e, f^2 = e, frf^{-1} = r^{-1} \rangle$$

Comment: Group is a set endowed with structure (binary operation $\circ$). Yes, which means the ordered pair $(G, \circ)$ is a group. Not the set $G$. $G$ is just the underlying set. Why should one include how things multiply in the **set** $G$, in the definition of $G$ when that is the job of $\circ$? $G$ is *supposed* to be just the list of elements, no? In this case, $D_n $ is supposed to just list down what elements come in $(D_n, \cdot)$ while the ordered pair $(D_n, \cdot)$ aka group should include the information of how things multiply, not $D_n$. Am I making sense?

Comment: Yes, but in your post you have given no definition of the multiplication in $D_n$, so you have in fact not defined $D_n$. Seen as a group, the definition of the elements in the underlying set is of little interest. That just boils down to notation. *Any* set with $2n$ elements may serve as the underlying set in a definition of $D_n$. The important thing is to explain how they multiply.

Comment: Oh is that what you were trying to say, my bad. I guess I was taking that for granted because it was irrelevant to my questions. But I see what you're trying to say. So let's **assume**, you could define how things multiply, for example $f_if_j$ is defined like this: reflecting in $j$-th axis of symmetry followed by reflecting in $i$-th axis of symmetry produces a rotation of $n-$gon through twice the angle between the axes, I don't know. Just assume you could define multiplication in some meaningful way. Then see, my questions.

Comment: P.S. Though that was not my actual question, it was a great point. Any set with $2n$ does the job, what matters is how they multiply. That is, if $x\cdot y$ in $(G,\cdot)$ is the same as multiplying their images $f(x) \circ f(y)$ in $(G', \circ)$ where $f$ is a bijection then $(G, \cdot)$ and $(G', \circ)$ are same regardless of the nature of elements they have, extremely helpful point that demonstrates why group is not just a set but also about how those elements relate to each other.